# how do i hide /magento/ in my site's url?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, magento

A site has an existing system (lets call it *mysite*)
and the client asks to put in magento.

My directory structure goes something like this:

```
ROOT       
   -index.php (this is the app's main controller)
   -.htaccess
   /blog (runs wordpress)
   /assets (current system's media folder)
   /magento (this is where all magento files go)
```

Problem is if I set up magento and specify in the installation that base URL is `http://example.com`, magento loads up *mysite*.

Leaves me no choice but to setup magento with base URL set to `http://example.com/magento/` and it runs perfectly.
However the client wants me to feel hell and asks me to hide magento in the URL.

I’m not really versed in .htaccess and I know only simple rewrite codes so I tried forwarding any HTTP requests that start with `/magento` to the *magento* folder and came up with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/magento(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) /magento/$1 [L]
```

Just when I thought it was working, *mysite* links all became unaccessible and forwards to the magento system displaying it's 404 page.

So, uhm, can I ask for help how to construct the .htaccess to hide the `/magento/` on the URLs without affecting the current system aka *mysite*?

Comment: I think that depends on your current system *mysite*. If it also uses rewriting techniques, there is no way to distinguish what requests should be redirected to what system (*mysite* or magento). So what does your system *mysite* look like? How are the requests processed?

Comment: well the current htaccess in the root directory is this
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA]
so that anything that is not found gets forwarded to the index of root...

Answer (score 3):

Because you have existing applications off the webroot, you cannot get away with using *nothing* instead:

```
### webroot/.htaccess
RewriteRule ^whatiwanttouseinsteadofmagento/(.*)$ magento/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

From how I see the problem you will not be able to hide magento completely and use your site as well in the same time.

If you want Magento in the root of the public folder you should just point the virtualHost to your magento installation but this will let your blog and your main controller out of the public view. This is more or less the same with what you did by redirecting all calls in the .htaccess to magento folder.

What I suggest is to change the magento name to something more *anonymous* like "shopping" or "cart", and remember that a folder rename is preferable to a .htaccess file in terms of security and performance.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at it:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/magento(.*)
```

So we're saying the condition is anything that is not /magento(.*), so everything but that directory? This would redirect everything, including your blog, assets, and any other directories.

Without specifying each and every file that needs to be redirected to the magento directory, there really is no easy way of doing it. I suppose you could redirect any file that does not contain a "/" in it and ends with the extension .php to the magento directory. That way only files in the root web directory will redirect to magento, but if you used other directories inside the magento directory you'd still need to add separate rules for them.

Answer (score 0):

this answer comes very late but I guess you wanted something like

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(blog|assets|magento)(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /magento$1 [L]
```